# Stripe & Node.js - "Cannot POST /create-checkout-session"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm trying to follow the Stripe Checkout subscription instructions:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=checkout

When I submit the form, over localhost I get `"Cannot POST /create-checkout-session"` (404 in network tab), and if I run from my production server, it just opens `/create-checkout-session` as a new (blank) Vue page. I have tried changing the form action to `https://mydomain.xyz/create-checkout-session`, but it didn't work.

Subscribe.vue

```html
<form action="/create-checkout-session" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="priceId" value="[removed for Stack Overflow]" />
  <button type="submit">Checkout</button>
</form>
```

I don't know if something is interfering with the endpoint, so I've copied my entire app.js file:

app.js

```js
let express = require('express'),
  cors = require('cors'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  database = require('./database'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
const stripe = require('stripe')('[removed for StackOverflow]');

//connect mongoDB
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(database.db, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => {
  console.log("Database connected")
  },
  error => {
    console.log("Database couldn't be connected to: " + error);
  }
)

const cryptoEndPoint = require('../backend/routes/crypto.route')
const app = express();
                app.use(decodeIDToken);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(cors())

//API
app.use('/api', cryptoEndPoint)


app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {

  console.log("can't even get anything to console log, only get createError is not defined");
  const { priceId } = req.body;

  // Create new Checkout Session for the order
  // Other optional params include:
  // [billing_address_collection] - to display billing address details on the page
  // [customer] - if you have an existing Stripe Customer ID
  // [customer_email] - lets you prefill the email input in the form
  // [automatic_tax] - to automatically calculate sales tax, VAT and GST in the checkout page
  // For full details see https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create
  try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      mode: 'subscription',
      line_items: [
        {
          price: priceId,
          // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      // {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} is a string literal; do not change it!
      // the actual Session ID is returned in the query parameter when your customer
      // is redirected to the success page.
      success_url: 'https://mydomain.xyz/thankyou?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      cancel_url: 'https://mydomain.xyz/thankyou',
    });

    return res.redirect(303, session.url);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400);
    return res.send({
      error: {
        message: e.message,
      }
    });
  }
});


//create port
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Connected to port ' + port);
})

//Find 404
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(createError(404));
})

//error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.log(err.message);
  if (!err.statusCode) err.statusCode = 500;
  res.status(err.statusCode).send(err.message);
})




            /**
             * Decodes the JSON Web Token sent via the frontend app
             * Makes the currentUser (firebase) data available on the body.
             */
            async function decodeIDToken(req, res, next) {
              if (req.headers?.authorization?.startsWith('Bearer ')) {

                const idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];

                // console.log(idToken);

                try {
                  const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
                  // console.log("one");
                  req['currentUser'] = decodedToken;
                  // console.log("two");
                } catch (err) {
                  console.log("error: " + err);
                }
              }

              next();
            }



            app.post("/webhook", async (req, res) => {
              let data;
              let eventType;
              // Check if webhook signing is configured.
              const webhookSecret = '[removed for Stack Overflow]'
              if (webhookSecret) {
                // Retrieve the event by verifying the signature using the raw body and secret.
                let event;
                let signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

                try {
                  event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
                    req.body,
                    signature,
                    webhookSecret
                  );
                } catch (err) {
                  console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`);
                  return res.sendStatus(400);
                }
                // Extract the object from the event.
                data = event.data;
                eventType = event.type;
              } else {
                // Webhook signing is recommended, but if the secret is not configured in `config.js`,
                // retrieve the event data directly from the request body.
                data = req.body.data;
                eventType = req.body.type;
              }

              switch (eventType) {
                  case 'checkout.session.completed':
                    //...
                    break;
                  case 'invoice.paid':
                    //...
                    break;
                  case 'invoice.payment_failed':
                    //...
                    break;
                  default:
                    
                  // Unhandled event type
                }

              res.sendStatus(200);
            });
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: in your vue.js, api endpoint should be /api/create-checkout-session

Comment: I don't think so as it's not defined like that, and I just tried it again and get ``Cannot POST /api/create-checkout-session``

Comment: Do you have an issue only with this route, or other routes are not working either ? Also have you tried to use express.Router instead of app.use to make up your routes ?

Comment: @liguepk it's only this route that's not working. I just tried with express.Router and that gives the same error — ``Cannot POST /create-checkout-session``

Comment: If your express server is not the one serving your frontend (for example you access them using different ports) you might need to specify the whole URL in your form's `action` attribute

Comment: @nickfla1, I tried that — "I have tried changing the form action to https://mydomain.xyz/create-checkout-session", but got the same result

Comment: You can try with a simpler server with only one POST route and see if it makes any difference. I didn't get the "createError is not defined" comment btw, I see it's not imported anywhere, does removing the 404 handler change anything?

Comment: @nickfla1, I've managed to get the route working in localhost, but when I try it on production, including by specifying the whole URL in my form's action attribute, it doesn't work — it just opens ``mydomain.xyz/create-checkout-session`` as a blank Vue page

Comment: How are you running `app.js` on your server?

Comment: are you seeing any errors in your server logs? it is possible that it is causing your server to not respond with the right information.

Comment: Sounds like a reverse proxy or routing problem, or just that the API sits on a different host. Probably try doing XHR to that route along with the complete API URL.

Comment: I've got it working now. I'll create an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to my app.js file, and it's working:

```js
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
}

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```